# Multiple commands produce Carthage

Tags: xcode, carthage

I'm using Carthage in my project and currently trying to migrate from `.framework` to `.xcframework`.
I've done all the steps described in the Carthage docs(https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#migrating-a-project-from-framework-bundles-to-xcframeworks).

Xcode shows compilation error due to "Multiple commands produce ... ".

No duplicate items in `Copy bundle resources`. I've only put the `.xcframeworks` to the list of `General > Frameworks, Librararies and Embedded Content`.

Build folder and derived data are empty.

Xcode version - 12.5.1

[image]Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to solve this? Thanks